# How i can calculate the time spend during garbage collection?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, garbage-collection, measurement

I want to calculate a time spend by garbage collection during a method like

```
//code
testfunction()
//code

//display the time spend by garbage collection when we was in the testfunction 
Display(GarbageCollectionTime(testfunction))
```

I looked on 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

But i can't understand how to do it.

Please can someone have any idea on how to do it.

Comment: A JVM profiler is probably capable of this. I use VerySleepy for my c++ projects, and it shows time spent in the destructor of an object. Something similar probably exists for Java that doesn't require any extra code to work. I honestly wouldn't be surprised if it came with the JDK.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it's about c# .net not java And i hope if i someone can help me with that

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I don't know why I thought it was Java. Did you google "C# Profiler"?

Comment: Yes it's why i putted the link too i check them their is a profiler % Time in GC but i don't know what it return i need time and the values are strange

Comment: This is not a meaningful measurement.  The odds that the GC will collect while testfunction() is running are completely random.  You can only measure the proportion of GC collect time vs program execution time over long periods.

Comment: @HansPassant  what do u mean about long perdiod if i test GC.collectionCount i see that lot of collection was made after the testFunction it's not depending on long time but on the data used

Comment: Can we do it if use GC notifications ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @HansPassant what's the problem with my question ?

Comment: Nobody knows what problem you are trying to solve, we can only tell that, whatever it might be, you are doing it wrong.  You cannot get good advice when you don't tell us.

Comment: as i told u i want to know if their is way to measure the gc time durring a execution code and like that i can subsract it from the time measured for the function to get the function time without gc times

Answer (score 2):

You can try [JetBrains dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory). dotTrace show special node [Garbage Collection] under your method in call tree. dotMemory can show you everything you may want to know about your memory and little bit more.

Answer (score 2):

> subsract it from the time measured for the function to get the function time without gc times

You want to benchmark without GC influence. Put the GC into low latency mode. This will postpone most expensive GC cycles until you lift the lot latency mode.

```
GCSettings.LatencyMode = GCLatencyMode.LowLatency;
```

There's also the newer `SustainedLowLatency`. I don't know what it does but it might be more aggressive. Read the docs.

Now this is not a completely valid benchmark because if your function allocates the GC time kind of is part of that function. It is better to measure the function many many times and include many GC cycles so that amortized GC time is part of the benchmark.